# How to merge "archetype-catalog.xml" from different repositories into a single Maven group repository In nexus3

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to aggregate archetypes from multiple releases repositories into a single "maven-public" distribution group in an internal nexus.

All the archetypes are available to download in the group repository but it looks like is not compiling an aggregated version of the catalogs, the catalog it serves is the one from the first repository of the group.

Is this doable? All the examples I see around retrieve the catalog from the releases repository directly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all member repositories of the maven group I found out that one of the proxy repositories had an invalid catalog and it was messing up the merge of the rest of catalogs.
Removing that repository from the group fixed the problem.